# Can bookmarklets store configuration data?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

As I understand, [bookmarklets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet) are executed with the origin of the page, where they are invoked. While this is pretty much the very reason they are useful, it limits the ability of the bookmarklet to keep state.

Specifically, I want to store configuration data for a bookmarklet. A use-case would be e.g. allowing persistent site-independent customization of the behaviour, without changing the code.

Additional criteria would include

- Protecting bookmarklet configuration from unwanted access by other bookmarklets
- Sharing bookmarklet cofiguration with trusted other bookmarklets
- Protecting bookmarklet configuration from possible malicious websites.

An extreme example would be a bookmarklet syncing content with a third-party file hosting service like Dropbox, which would require securely storing an authentication key.

Is there any such possibility?

#### Additional notes

- I am primarily using iOS to add behaviour on iOS and Windows. The iOS-part prevents the use of browser extensions (which anyway would limit portability).
- I am trying to use bookmarklets specifically because I *don't* have access to a server, so some techniques used in bookmarklets related to webservices don't apply.

#### Possible Workarounds I thought of

- Configuration might be put in the bookmarklet manually, e.g. by hosting the main javascript on a public service like github, and creating a proxy bookmarklet that loads it with `#`-options, e.g.

  ```
  javascript:function runBmlet(url){ var s=document.createElement("script"); s.src=url; document.head.appendChild(s); }; runBmlet("http://url.of/my/script.js#DropboxData=YOURDATAHERE");
  ```

  which is however much less convenient on the long run than storing the configuration in something akin to localStorage.

  **edit** That solution sadly doesn't work at all; Some webpages block loading javascript from untrusted sources with a policy `script-src 'unsafe-eval' ...`, and including the javascript file e.g. from Dropbox or Github is prevented by mime-type checking.

Comment: Bookmarklets can use cookies and localStorage - anything that can be stored in the scope of the page they are run. Bookmarklets can create webbugs and ajax crossdomain if CORS is enabled. So you can do anything in a bookmarklet, you can do in a web page including including other javascripts. That could be an external JS that gets the AUTH from a database hosted elsewhere

Comment: @mplungjan In my use-case, sadly, there isn't anything hosted elsewhere, or at best in web-services like Dropbox, which I have no control over.

Comment: Why? You can host such things on loads of free servers or your own server

Comment: I didn't know about the "free server" option; A self-hosted version would be doable too if needed (Raspberry Pi or such). I would be more interested though in solutions, that allow passing by code to others, with neither central data storage for all users, nor the need to set up their own servers. Hence the idea of (ab?)using bookmarklets for such a purpose.

Comment: Sorry that is not doable in my opinion

Comment: The dropbox idea (host big javascript file on dropbox, load with script tag) also broke down, I'll update the "workarounds" part.

Comment: Hey, I know this is like two years late, but are you still looking for a solution, or did you find one?

Comment: Bottom line was, that it isn't doable. Bookmarklets are simply not a relevant design consideration for browser security models :(